# Rectangular box pattern X with fill right of 1/4 in python

Tags: python

I wrote a program to print a rectangular box pattern in python . But I need edit that fill 1/4 of right of box with '#'

this is just  print a rectangular box pattern in python

```
def pattern(n):
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        if (i == 0 or i == n - 1
                or j == 0 or j == n - 1
                or i == j or i == n - 1 - j):
            print("#", end="")

        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print("")

 input:7
 #  output
 #######
 ##   ##
 # # # #
 #  #  #
 # # # #
 ##   ##
 #######


but I need
#######
##   ##
# # ###
#  ####
# # ###
##   ##
#######
```

Comment: You're looking for values that fall between these two conditions `i == j or i == n - 1 - j` so try adding `or (i < j and i > n -1 -j)`

Answer (score 2):

```
def pattern(n):
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            if (i == 0 or i == n - 1
                    or j == 0 or j == n - 1
                    or i == j or i == n - 1 - j
                    or (i < j and i > n -1 -j)):
                print("#", end="")

            else:
                print(" ", end="")
        print("")


print (pattern(15))
```

out:

```
###############
##           ##
# #         ###
#  #       ####
#   #     #####
#    #   ######
#     # #######
#      ########
#     # #######
#    #   ######
#   #     #####
#  #       ####
# #         ###
##           ##
###############
```